# CLI Data Loader Failure notification

Tags: data-loader, notification, force-cli

I am tryin to figure out but unable to sure as what seems to be available in the available resource is that whenever the CLI Dataloader fails, User will not be able to get the notification.

Just to clear the doubt I am trying to confirm if :

1. CSV file process fail admin / user (outside SF) will receive any
   error mail / if not a workaround
2. In case any record fails in the csv
   CRUD process salesforce admin / user (outside SF) will receive an
   email.

Comment: I have checked further and it seems it cannot be done until we can read the logs generated automatically .ref( http://www.nimbleuser.com/blog/posts/2012/failing-safe-with-the-apex-data-loader-for-salesforce-crm/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running data loader from the command line you are running an app that is using the Salesforce API to write data to Salesforce.

If you want email notification on failures, the way to do that would then be through the app, or by way of the process that invokes the app (the batch or shell script that invokes the cli).

At a high level you would want your script to do the following:

1. Invoke the data loader CLI
2. Once the result is returned, read the error file
3. If there are errors, send an email

How you send the email does depend on the operating system the automated process is running from. For Windows, this [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/120011/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-send-email-from-the-command-line-in-windows-without-extra-software/) shows how to send an email using a powershell script that uses a remote SMTP server (gmail in this instance). For Unix/Linux, this [article](http://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/#) shows some options for how to invoke and send email.